# Using SELECT clause inside AVG function

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
table: people
id  |   name    |   income
==========================
1    Bob         10
2    John        5
3    Amy         15
4    Alyson      5
5    Henry       20
```

I want to take the average of only a select number of rows, like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (AVG(
        SELECT income FROM people WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,3')
    ) - income) AS averageDiff
FROM people;
```

I expect to get a result like this:

```
id  |   name    |   averageDiff
==========================
1    Bob         0
2    John        5
3    Amy         -5
4    Alyson      -5
5    Henry       10
```

However, I get an error (#1064) when trying to use the SELECT clause inside of the AVG function. How can I do this?

Comment: And what do you want for the other rows? Can you show an example of expected result for the given 5 rows table?

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
SELECT avg(income) FROM people WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,3')
```

You need to enclose the above query in brackeds in this way:

```
SELECT
......
    (ABS(IFNULL(`age`, 0)  
      - IFNULL((SELECT AVG(age) FROM people WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,3')), 0)))
    + (ABS(IFNULL(`income`, 0) 
       - IFNULL((SELECT AVG(income) FROM people WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,3')), 0))) AS sumAvg
FROM `people`
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average for everybody as your starting point, calculate that with a query and cross join it to the people you want to include:

```
SELECT
  people.id,
  people.name,
  people.income - av.avgincome AS averageDiff
FROM people
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(income) AS avgincome FROM people) av
WHERE people.ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

If you want the average for the subset of people with ID 1, 2 or 3 as your starting point you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  people.id,
  people.name,
  people.income - av.avgincome AS averageDiff
FROM people
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT AVG(income) AS avgincome
  FROM people
  WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)) av
WHERE people.ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Both approaches avoid the correlated subquery (meaning a `SELECT` for a column name based on the top-level table), which is slow with large recordsets.

The `FIND_IN_SET(people.id, '1,2,3') will work, but if you have an index on`table.id`the`IN (1, 2, 3)` will be much faster. It will probably be faster even if you don't have the index.